# 'Man mano' e 'via via' versus locuzioni alternative

Tags: word-choice, idioms

> … tale sensazione viene meno *man mano* che il lettore si addentra nell'opera e comincia a provare interesse per …

Generalmente, anche se non riesco a spiegare perché, non uso *man mano*, e nel precedente frammento non solo questa locuzione c'è, ma è anche preceduta da *meno*, in una successione *meno*, *man*, *mano* che sembra alquanto sgradevole.

Sapreste suggerire una locuzione alternativa che, però, non sia *via via*, che non mi piace?

Cosa pensate circa *in misura*?

> … tale sensazione viene meno *in misura* che il lettore si addentra nell'opera e comincia a provare interesse per …

Answer (score 5):

La locuzione con “misura” che è sinonimo di “via via che” è “a misura che”. Si veda come riferimento il punto 4.f della [voce “misura” del dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/misura/), in cui è per esempio riportata una frase di Primo Levi: «a misura che la neve andava scomparendo, il campo si mutava in uno squallido acquitrino».

Answer (score 4):

"In misura che" senz'altro è errata, la locuzione che cerchi è "nella misura in cui". Tuttavia, se il significato della frase risulta simile, mi sembra che dia un sentore di più "clinicamente preciso" alla frase, quando l'originale è volutamente vago.

Per me "via via" è la più adatta, o in alternativa puoi sostituire il "viene meno" con "si attenua", "passa in secondo piano", "sparisce", "scompare", o altri verbi di significato simile.

Comment: "nella misura in cui" ha un significato quantitativo, "man mano" uno progressivo.
"Man mano che scalavano la montagna, la vegetazione si faceva sempre piu rada". " Nella misura in cui la regione si impegna a potenziare i finanziamenti, l'azienda trasporti deve farsi carico del rinnovamento dei vagoni."

Answer (score 3):

Another possible alternative is

«… tale sensazione viene progressivamente meno all'addentrarsi del lettore nell'opera, cominciando questi a provare interesse per …»

or also

«… tale sensazione viene progressivamente meno mentre il lettore si addentra nell'opera e comincia a provare interesse per …»

Answer (score 1):

Si potrebbe usare anche: *pian piano*

> tale sensazione viene pian piano meno mentre/quando il lettore si addentra nell'opera e comincia a provare interesse per …

O anche:

> tale sensazione viene pian piano meno all' addentrarsi del lettore nell'opera e mentre comincia a provare interesse per...

Comment: se dici "viene pian piano meno" devi rigirare tutto il resto della frase, però

Comment: @mau non mi è chiaro cosa intendi, non basta dire: "...viene meno pian piano che..."

Comment: no, così non mi sembra proprio italiano.

Comment: Per favore, potresti ampliare la risposta? Mi sembra però che la sequenza *meno pian piano* non sia bellissima.

Answer (score 0):

Puoi anche passare a una temporale:

> … tale sensazione viene meno *quando* il lettore si addentra nell'opera e comincia a provare interesse per …

Comment: Non è la stessa cosa, manca l'idea di attenuazione/accrescimento graduale.

Answer (score 0):

L'uso di "più" può essere una valida alternativa che conferisce l'idea di progressivo accrescimento.

> … tale sensazione viene meno più il lettore si addentra nell'opera e comincia a provare interesse per …

Inoltre la contrapposizione dei termini "meno" e "più" è un ottimo gioco di parole laddove si legga "meno" allungando un poco più del dovuto l'accento sulla "e": "meeno".

Comment: Non sono sicuro di cogliere l'efficacia dell'allungamento della “e” di “meno”, ma se devo essere sincero questo accostamento tra “meno” e “più” non mi suona molto felice: se fosse un testo che devo rivedere ne consiglierei una modifica, perché è una di quelle frasi in cui la prima lettura rischia di incespicare e di dover tornare sui suoi passi.

Comment: Concordo con DaG, anche se il gioco forse si può rendere con "più il lettore si addentra nell'opera [...], più tale sensazione viene meno"

Comment: … tale sensazione viene a mancare _più_ il lettore si addentra nell'opera e comincia a provare interesse per …