# Sull'uso di "a mano a mano", "man mano" e "mano a mano"

Tags: word-usage

So che le locuzioni "a mano a mano", "man mano" e "mano a mano" significano successivamente, progressivamente, a poco a poco. Mi chiedo però se queste si usano ugualmente o se invece qualcuna si usa di più delle altre, o se ci sono differenze di registro nell'uso di queste espressioni.

Ho trovato esempi di uso di tali locuzioni in alcuni libri che ho letto:

> ***A mano a mano:***
>
> - Si sentiva a mano a mano, col sangue, mancar la vita, a mano a mano le forze raffievolendo scemare; era già fredda... (Luigi Pirandello, *Scialle Nero*).
> - A mano a mano ho postillato il mio libro, ho aggiunto fogli e foglietti e il mio viaggio non è più alle mie spalle, è presente e futuro, si specchia negli occhi delle mie donne (Maria Bellonci, *Marco Polo*).

> ***Man mano:***
>
> - Man mano che avanzavano verso lo studio, una girava l'interruttore e l'altra lo spegneva nella stanza precedente col ritmo e la sincronia di un balletto privo di musica (Simonetta Agnello Hornby, *La mennulara*).
> - Man mano che procedeva nella scrittura l'autore era assalito dall'ansia della comunicazione (dalla *Premessa* di Giocchino Lanza Tomasi per l'edizione di Feltrinelli di *Il Gattopardo* di Giuseppe Tomasi di Lampedusa).
> - Man mano che procedeva la corsa sentiva calmarsi la furia che lo aveva posseduto per tutta la vita (Mariolina Venezia, *Mille anni che sto qui*).

> Di ***"mano a mano"*** non ho trovato nessun esempio nei miei libri, ma sì su Google Books:
>
> - Mano a mano che il monologo procede, percepisco, nelle sue parole, un formidabile disprezzo per “gli altri”, per quella insulsa parte del genere umano che non figura nel novero degli “iniziati” alla politica (Giancarlo de Cataldo, *In giustizia*).

Comment: *Mano a mano*, come *poco a poco*, è un uso deprecabile (vorrei dire errato, ma in queste faccende non si usa).

Comment: Non è proprio un doppione, ma può interessare anche [questa domanda](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1618/man-mano-e-via-via-vs-locuzioni-alternative) e relative risposte.

Comment: Come già detto, "a mano a mano" è un'espressione che si riferisce alla gradualità di compiere un'azione. Curiosità: [è anche il titolo di un famoso brano di Rino Gaetano, qui il testo](http://www.notetralerighe.it/testi-canzoni/mano-mano-testo-rino-gaetano).

Answer (score 4):

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=man%20mano%2Ca%20mano%20a%20mano%2Cmano%20a%20mano&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cman%20mano%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bman%20mano%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMan%20mano%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ca%20mano%20a%20mano%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20mano%20a%20mano%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BA%20mano%20a%20mano%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmano%20a%20mano%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmano%20a%20mano%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMano%20a%20mano%3B%2Cc0) mostra che tutte e tre le espressioni sono molto comuni.

> - Secondo [Treccani online](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/a-mano-a-mano-a-poco-a-poco-a-due-a-due_(La_grammatica_italiana)/)   'a mano a mano' è preferibile rispetto 'mano a mano' in caso di locuzione avverbiali,  ma quando invece queste locuzioni vengono usate in funzione di sostantivo, la prima 'a' va sempre omessa.

USI:

> - Al posto della locuzione 'a mano a mano', è molto frequente l’espressione 'man mano': 
>     Man mano che si scende, il Po si ingrossa.

Comment: Immagino che Ngram includa i casi di "a mano a mano" in quelli di "mano a mano". Dunque forse si può concludere che "mano a mano" (senza la preposizione "a") non è tanto usata.

Comment: Cosa vuol dire "mano a mano" in funzione di sostantivo?

Comment: @Charo -  Si intende usato come nome, nel caso di 'a mano a mano' e' raro, ma altre forme simili come 'a faccia a faccia' possono venire usate come sostantivi. Ad esempio 'un faccia a faccia'. In conclusione: 'a mano a mano' e 'man mano' sono le forme piu corrette.

Answer (score 4):

"Man mano" è l'espressione generalmente più usata, probabilmente perché più breve e scorrevole. Nella scrittura personalmente preferisco "a mano a mano" ma nell'espressione orale utilizzo "man mano". Considerala pure come una forma contratta.

Answer (score 1):

Le locuzioni "a mano a mano", "man mano" e "mano a mano" sono perfettamente equivalenti e interscambiabili, sì.

Il "registro linguistico" cui appartengono è quello usato da coloro che preferiscono esprimere concetti astratti attraverso metafore, cioè quasi tutti.

Qui la metafora è quella della corda che tirata alternativamente e ciclicamente, prima con una mano e poi con l'altra, solleva un qualche carico fino a portarlo progressivamente ad un predefinito punto d'arrivo.

Io, comunque, non gradisco lo scrivere o il parlare per metafore e, nel caso in questione, preferirei usare formulazioni differenti.(†)

Per esempio, a "Mano a mano che il monologo procede, ..." preferirei "Al procedere del monologo, ..." e a "Man mano che procedeva nella scrittura l'autore ..." preferirei "A misura che procedeva nella scrittura[,] l'autore ...".

(†) Ovviamente la scrittura di Luigi Pirandello, essendo corretta in sé e di per sé, è fuori da qualsiasi discussione.

Comment: *A misura che procedeva* mi sembra piuttosto brutto.

Answer (score 1):

Come già detto, "a mano a mano" è più scritto che parlato e viceversa per "man mano".

Io ne farei anche una questione di ritmo: "a mano a mano", ripetuto e scandito, rende (personalmente) l'idea di un'azione che scorre più lentamente. "man mano" è più "rapido" e immediato.

Gli esempi riportati nella domanda mi danno la stessa impressione.